# Using Flash FLVPlayback component with skin on Facebook (FBML)

Tags: flash, facebook, actionscript, fbml, flvplayback

I'm trying to insert a player on a Facebook Page tab with FBML with `fb:swf`. I have the following:

```
<fb:swf 
  imgsrc="http://IP/player/player.gif" 
  swfsrc="http://IP/player/player.swf" 
  flashvars="source=http://IP/player/movie.flv"
  swfbgcolor="000000"
  wmode="opaque"
  quality="best"
  width="520"
  height="430" />
```

I can see the video, no problem. It plays inside a `FLVPlayback` component, which uses a skin (referred by `/player/skinName.swf`, I tried also the absolute path here). This player works perfectly everywhere else (even on an `iframe` Facebook application, where it's not inserted using the `fb:swf` tag, but with `object`, of course). However, I can't see the skin on the Page tab.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the html that is generated by the `<fb:swf/>` tag. Maybe the generated code add some attributes to the `<object>/<embed>` which restrain its access to external sources, somehow.

Also, you have access to the skin's server, I suppose. Check if there is any request to the skin file (this may help with debugging).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried capturing the response to the /player/skinName.swf request in Firebug? If so what is the status? 404? 403? Is it not even requested but a crossdomain.xml request returns 404? I think you might be able more accurately debug using these.